# Get data from object using FireBase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

Currently i have an object from the FireBase database. Like so:
[image]

I want to render this data using React for now i have:

```
return (
   <React.Fragment>
      <StyledMain role="main">
        <Layout currentUser={currentUser}>
          <ListCards currentUser={currentUser} />
            {data.map((item, index) => (
              <Card id={Object.keys(item).toString()} key="c" type="chats">
                <CardContent scrollbar={false}>
                  <Grid columns={`${rem(300)} 1fr`} scrollbar={false}>
                    {Object.keys(item).map(function(key, index) {
                      <Text text={item[key]['type'].toString()} />;
                     })}
                  </Grid>
               </CardContent>
             </Card>
           ))}
        </Layout>
     </StyledMain>
   </React.Fragment>
);
```

Having `data` containing the firebase Widgets object.
My goal is to render `Card` where the `id` is `erf4553o459g4` and the `Text` component will render `lists` 
What is the best approach to accomplish this? Two `map` functions sounds a bit  unnecessary.

The function to get the data from FireBase:

```
const getSingleRefFunction = (ref, callback) => {
  const dataArray = [];

  ref.once('value', snap => {
    dataArray.push(snap.val());
    callback(dataArray);
  });
};
```

Comment: if you got nested lists which you want to render, a nested `map` sounds like the way to go. you may abstract the second `map` inside a nested component but it will remain a nested `map` loop either way of course

Comment: Could you please show an example of the resulting `data` array that you call `.map` on?